# Hausdorff dimension of higher powers of the Mandebrot set ?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory

My third question about Shishikura's result :

Shishikura (1991) proved that the Hausdorff Dimension of the boundary of the Mandelbrot set equals 2, in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9201282)1. The Mandelbrot set is defined by iterating to infinity the z^2+c map.

Does his result also apply for higher powers, such as z^8 + c ?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does.  See the full statement of Theorem 2 on page 6.  The assumptions of the theorem are:

> Suppose that a rational map $f_0$ of degree $d\ (> 1)$ has a parabolic fixed
>   point ζ with multiplier exp(2πip/q) ($p, q \in\mathbb{Z}, \mathit{gcd}(p, q) = 1$) and that the immediate parabolic basin of ζ contains only one critical point of $f_0$.

This is the case for $z^d+c$.

Comment: Indeed - and by universality of the Mandelbrot and Mulitbrot sets (proved by McMullen), the same will be true in any non-trivial one-dimensional family you can think up.